# Unable to get the empty User Form

Tags: angular

My code is only working for loading the data with edit button and i'm able to update the data!!! but when i click on AddNew vehicle option in the menu to add new data i'm getting the form with loaded value of last edited. Not getting the Empty form to add new data.

If i haven't clicked on edit button then AddNew vehicle option in the menu to add new data i'm getting the Empty form to add new data.

How can I fix this issue.

My Code is available at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz

Comment: In grid data is not loaded because they calling localhost api.

Comment: Please check your link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz. The grid has no data!

Comment: Please Do check my code is displaying with sample data.

Comment: @AVINASHM you probably should send the user object with empty values for each key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are redirecting to the same route. Hence angular preventing it.

> Just put this much of code into the constructor of the component (`user-form.components.ts`) where you want to navigate to.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
  return false;
};

this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    this.router.navigated = false;      
});
```

**Also, add a callback function for menu click:**

```
   items: [
        { 
          label: 'Add New Vehicle', icon: 'fa fa-refresh',  
          command: () => {
          let user = new User();
          this._userService.setter(user);
          this.router.navigate(['/op']);  
          }  
        },
        { label: 'Show All', icon: 'fa fa-repeat', url: '#' }
      ]
```

**Working code link:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjhvtj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
**Working example link:** https://angular-xjhvtj.stackblitz.io

Comment: if i'm on the userform screen currently and if i click on add new vehicle menu then it will not work...i have the same functionality before also.If i was in the home page i'm able to get the empty form.

Answer (score 0):

You could add at the end of your processForm() function in user-form.component the following code:

```
this.user = undefined;
```

or

```
this.user = new User(); # For an empty one
```

So the next time you navigate to /op route and then the user-form component is called the data must be recovered again

Comment: i have tried this but not working my code available at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz